# Unable to customize the grid tile in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have implemented a simple grid list in angular using angular material and angular flex layout.

I need to align the grid as shown in the image below....
[image]

But I am unable to customize the grid tile and place as shown in the image above..

please access my [sample app here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-r4s19h?file=app%2Fgridlist.component.ts)

I am trying to apply many different styles but unable to match the required one ... can anybody please solve my issue.....?

Comment: Grid list should not be used for layout structuring purposes. You should be able to accomplish the desired layout using flex-layout.

Comment: p4r1 is right, try something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gktbhw